# Including optional inputs into a program?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, plaintext, ppm

I was wondering if there was a way to create optional inputs into my code? I'm programming a code that will print out RGB values for a 480x480 plaintext image. The code should allow me to input 4 optional values in any order - 
-r x
scales the sin of the red component of each pixel by double x,
-g x
does the same as -r, except for with the green component
-b x
does the same, but with blue
-s n
specifies the side length of the image for integer n.

Here's my code:

```
int* arrayfill()
{
int* bmult;
 bmult = malloc(sizeof(int)*480*480);
for (int y = 0; y < 480; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 480; x++) {
    bmult[x + y*480] = (128*sin( sqrt(pow(x-240,2) + pow(y-240,2)))+128);
    if (0 <= (bmult[x + y*480]) || (bmult[x + y*480]) >= 255) {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      fprintf(stderr, "The scale must result in a b value between 0 & 255");
      break;
    }
  }}
 return bmult;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int* newarray = arrayfill();
  printf(" P3\n");
  printf("480 480\n");
  printf("255\n");
  for (int count = 0; count < 480*480; count++) {
    printf("0, 0, %d\n", newarray[count]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an option parser. Which parts do you need help with? Look at basically any command-line tool (post circa 1985?)

Comment: This is what `argc` and `argv[]` are for. However, I would suggest following @tripleee's advice and use a command-line parsing library to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getopt` (and `getopt_long`).

> The getopt and getopt_long functions automate some of the chore
>   involved in parsing typical unix command line options.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html for usage and examples.